# Magento1.8 redirection to payu, cart empty on back button

Tags: magento

We are using payu for our magento site, after installing pay u when user redirects to pay u site and clicks on browser back button without dong payment, the cart is empty on return. I get no error. This issue is not there with Paypal. Please help me.

Thanks,
Dileep

Comment: As far as I know, this is how Magento works. When you click place order, a new order is created, all quote items are converted to order items, and everything is removed from cart.

Comment: I got empty cart on return from payu site

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

As Hashid has mentioned, once the "place order" button has been pressed and the customer is redirected to the PSP page, the order is created in Magento. I know that for example Ogone has a cancel button on their PSP page, which will restore your cart if you press it. A browser back function won't do anything to restore the cart.

I don't have much experience with editing those psp pages, but if you could add a button there yourself which goes to a cancel action, you can implement some logic to restore the cart of the customer with the contents of their order.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the info. With paypal the browser back works, so i am checking for payu site.